# VRRP and VRRP-Extended

Tags: brocade, vrrp

Is VRRP-E a completely separate standard than VRRP or does it just add on features to the VRRP standard? What are some major differences between VRRP and VRRP-E?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VRRP-E is Brocade only. From Brocade documentation:

> VRRP-E is a Brocade protocol that provides the benefits of VRRP
>   without the limitations. VRRP-E is unlike VRRP in the following ways:
>
> - There is no “Owner” router. You do not need to use an IP address configured on one of the Layer 3 Switches as the virtual router ID
>     (VRID), which is the address you are backing up for redundancy. The
>     VRID is independent of the IP interfaces configured in the Layer 3
>     Switches. As a result, the protocol does not have an “Owner” as VRRP
>     does.
> - There is no restriction on which router can be the default master router. In VRRP, the “Owner” (the Layer 3 Switch on which the IP
>     interface that is used for the VRID is configured) must be the default
>     Master.
>
> Brocade Layer 3 Switches configured for VRRP-E can interoperate only
>   with other Brocade Layer 3 Switches.

Answer (score 6):

The main current issue with the Brocade line is that you can only enable one at a time, per chassis. i.e. If you want to run VRRP-E, you'll never be able to run VRRP with another vendor on another port.

They are not compatible in any way. VRRP-E is proprietary.

Comment: I can't help but think this is a bad call on Brocades part but that could be my biased view. If you are going to create a proprietary extension then why not keep it completely separate so you can run VRRP (standard) on some ports and BVRRP (or other name) on other ports.

Comment: I've asked my contacts at Brocade that they need to change this. I see no technical reason it can't be that each group can run their own version. No word yet on whether this will change.